# Canvas: X value changing in console but not in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am pulling coordinates from an API and setting them to a class of Rectangle. When looping through the data array, I am able to create each rectangle, but when it comes to moving them, that is where I am having trouble.

The x coordinates are changing in the console at the setInterval of move(), but the squares themselves are not moving across the screen.

When I have `c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth, innerHeight);` in `move()`, all of the rectangles disappear. Without it, they do not move at all.

```
if(this % 6 === 0){
          c.fillStyle = "#000";
        } else {
        c.fillStyle = "" + this.color + "";
```

is referring to the data array and if the index is divisible by 6, make that square black. Although, in this context, it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

let xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "(api here)", false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 const data = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, vx, color) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.w = w;
      this.h = h;
      this.vx = vx;
      this.color = color;
    }
    draw() {
        c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        if(this % 6 === 0){
          c.fillStyle = "#000";
        } else {
        c.fillStyle = "" + this.color + "";
      }

    }
    move(){
    c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth, innerHeight);
     if (this.x > 800 || this.x < 0){
        this.vx = -this.vx;
      }
       this.x+= this.vx;
      c.beginPath();
       console.log("here is the x value:" + this.x);

  }
}

 for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    let info = data[i]
    let rec = new Rectangle(info.x, info.y, info.w, info.h, info.vx, info.color);
    rec.draw();
    setInterval(function() {
      rec.move();
    }, 50);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: setInterval(function() {
      rec.move();
    }, 50 * i);

Comment: That didn't change anything for me unfortunately @MarouenMhiri

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

1. You are only updating the position and not making the draw call again.
   Move the `rec.draw()` call inside your `setInterval`. **Remember, ordering is important. Ideally, you should `update()` first and `draw()` later.**

   ```
   setInterval(function() {
     rec.move();
     rec.draw();
   }, 50);
   ```
2. Also, remove these lines from the `move()` function as you don't want to clear the canvas every time you update the variables. Clear the canvas in the beginning of the `draw()` function. Plus, since you're dealing with `fillRect()`, you dont need to include `beginPath()`

   ```
   c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth, innerHeight);
   ...
   c.beginPath();
   ```
3. You first need to specify the `fillStyle` then proceed with drawing the rectangle using `fillRect()`, not the other way round. The `draw()` function should look like this:

   ```
   draw() {
       c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
       if(this % 6 === 0){               // <-- Not really sure what is going on here
           c.fillStyle = "#000";
       } else {
           c.fillStyle = "" + this.color + "";
       }
       c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   }
   ```
4. In the code block in point number #3 you are using the Modulus Operator `%` on the the instance of the class itself i.e. `this` and not a number. I'm assuming you want something like `this.x` in there.

Apart from the points above there are still a handful of issues with your code. But it's outside the context of this question.

**Edited for a final solution below:**

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Usng var as we are making an async request and need to update this variable
var data = null;

// An empty array to store our rectangles
var collection = [];

// Using an asyn request as we don't necessarily need to wait for this step
xhr.open('GET', '<api>', true)

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300){
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            dataLoaded();
        } else {
            // The request gave an error response
        }
    }
};

xhr.send();

function dataLoaded(){
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        let info = data[i];
        collection.push(new Rectangle(info.x, info.y, info.w, info.h, info.vx, info.color));
    }

    setInterval(animate, 50);
}

function animate(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        let rect = collection[i];

        rect.update();
        rect.draw();
    }
}

class Rectangle {

    constructor(x, y, w, h, vx, color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.vx = vx;
        this.color = color;
    }

    update(){
        if (this.x > 800 || this.x < 0){
            this.vx = -this.vx;
        }
        this.x += this.vx;
    }

    draw(){
        context.fillStyle = this.color;
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is getting me closer to where I need to be. The `(this % 6 === 0 )` is referring to the data array. If the index of the array is divisible by 6, make it black. Thus, referring to just this when looping through the data array.

The move function works great (thank you!) but the draw function causes the square to flicker rapidly as it is clearing the canvas each 50 milliseconds. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Okay. I understand what you want to do. But it will not work, as `this` is not a **number** but an **object** and any mathematical operation on an object will return `NaN` (Not a Number).

Comment: As I said at the end of my answer. There are a lot of issues in the way you've structured your code here. The rectangles are flickering because of the execution order. Code keeps clearing the canvas before it proceeds to draw the other rectangle. It's almost as if your code is fighting itself. Honestly, making changes here is just going to worsen it. The entire script needs to change. I can walk you through if you'd like.

Comment: That would be really helpful thank you!. I requested you on linkedin or you can email me at amandajmunch@gmail.com