# JavaScript value changes but canvas doesn't redraw with updated values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to implement John Conway's Game of Life in HTML using canvas and JavaScript.
In a 2D array I store the cell's x-y position and state (alive or dead).
I avoid the outer most cells to avoid having to worry about boundary conditions.
Using requestAnimationFrame, I clear the canvas, update the cells for the next generation based on the number of neighbors, then draw them.
I console log the states of the cells, which do change but for some reason they don't get updated in the canvas.
I have already used this link for reference, but to no avail:
[Canvas: X value changing in console but not in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492601/canvas-x-value-changing-in-console-but-not-in-canvas)

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var cv = document.querySelector('#cv');
var c = cv.getContext('2d');
var h = cv.height;
var w = cv.width;

//Cell class
function Cell(alive, x, y) {
    this.alive = alive;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.draw = function () {
        //c.beginPath();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        if(alive == true) {
            c.fillStyle = 'black';
            c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
        }
        else if(alive == false){
            c.fillStyle = 'white';
            c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
        }
        //c.stroke();
    }
}


//2d array to contain Cell objects
var cellArray = new Array(100);
for (var i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {
  cellArray[i] = new Array(70);
}
//initial drawing
for(var i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        var b = Math.round(Math.random() - 0.4);
        if(b == 1) {
            cellArray[i][j] = new Cell(true, i * 10, j * 10);
            cellArray[i][j].draw();
        }
        else {
            cellArray[i][j] = new Cell(false, i * 10, j * 10);
            cellArray[i][j].draw();
        }
    }
}

//find number of neghbor cells
function neighborSum(cell, i, j) {
    this.cell = cell;
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    var sum = 0;
    if(cellArray[i - 1][j - 1].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i][j - 1].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i - 1][j].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i + 1][j - 1].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i - 1][j + 1].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i + 1][j].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i][j + 1].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    if(cellArray[i + 1][j + 1].alive == true) {
        sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
}

//animate function
function play() {
    requestAnimationFrame(play);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

        //check surrounding neighbor cells
    for(var i = 1; i < cellArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for(var j = 1; j < 70 - 1; j++) {
            if( cellArray[i][j].alive == true &&  (  neighborSum(cellArray[i][j], i, j) > 3 ||   neighborSum(cellArray[i][j], i, j) < 2 )  ) {
                cellArray[i][j].alive = false;
            }
            else if(  cellArray[i][j].alive == true  && ( neighborSum(cellArray[i][j], i, j) == 3 || neighborSum(cellArray[i][j], i, j) == 2 )  ) {
                cellArray[i][j].alive = true;
            }
            else if(cellArray[i][j].alive == false &&  neighborSum(cellArray[i][j], i, j) == 3   ) {
                cellArray[i][j].alive = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //console.log(cellArray)

    //redraw cells alive or dead
    for(var i = 1; i < cellArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for(var j = 1; j < 70 - 1; j++) {
            cellArray[i][j].draw();
        }
    }
}

requestAnimationFrame(play);
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ew3046st/1/

Comment: without stroke, there is no drawing.

Comment: But where do add it? In my draw function I already put it there (uncommented, of course)

Comment: canvas is a painting machine, when you draw something, this is definitely fixed. if you want to move a painting part you have clean the last position before repainting the next one

Comment: I do that by clearing the canvas; then I check the next generation's state and update their value, then I redraw; my problem is why does the canvas not show that? The canvas clears and redraws but keeps using the same values despite changing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was able to fix the problem by removing the draw() function and instead I just directly call the fillRect() function in the requestAnimationFrame function. Also, fixed the behavior of the cells by adding another 2d array of the same size to store the state of the cells for the next generation:

```
...
for(var i = 1; i < cellArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for(var j = 1; j < 70 - 1; j++) {
            //cellArray[i][j].draw();
            c.beginPath();
            //cellArray[i][j].draw();
            if(cellArray[i][j].alive == true) {
                c.fillStyle = 'black';
                c.fillRect(cellArray[i][j].x, cellArray[i][j].y, 10, 10);
            }
            else if(cellArray[i][j].alive == false){
                c.fillStyle = 'white';
                c.fillRect(cellArray[i][j].x, cellArray[i][j].y, 10, 10);
            }
            c.stroke();
        }
    }
...
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7u19xpq/1/